# Which is the best approach to synchronize two databases (no ETL)

Tags: .net, database, azure

I am building an integration solution where i need to integrate two databases. These databases would be either MySQL og MSSQL. I never know what the source or the destination is.

Also i dont know how much data should be transferred. I plan to do this on a daily or hourly basis and not knowing how much data i should transfer this kind of limits my choices of technology.

Normally I would do this using some kind of ETL tool (such as Microsoft SSIS). But there is political circumstances that wont allow this.

My question is this. Which option should i choose (this is running Microsoft Azure).

I have already tried with some large databases and a REST service in asp.core but is stuck with a timeout. I have considered using a servicebus and some application for incrementally reading data and pushing it to the bus. If i could build this solution with incremental reads, why not use a REST service.

I keep going in circles here.

Anything I havent thought of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use StreamSets Data Collector.  It can replicate between hetrogenous databases; we use it between Oracle and Vertica.  It has the ability to read the archive logs for both MySQL and MS-SQL Server but I haven't tried that yet.  It will connect to and from pretty much any database that supports JDBC. The best part is that a single data pipeline can replicate whole schemas of tables.  We use one pipeline to replicate more than 100 tables from our high volume Oracle ERP to our Vertica ODS/data lake with less than a minute of lag. The only issue we saw was that Oracle's LogMiner was too slow for us (100% an Oracle problem) so we wrote a bit of PL/SQL to facilitate the CDC for deletes. And to it off, StreamSets is Apache License open source, posted on GitHub, with options for paid support. Hard to argue with free.

Comment: Great tip - I will definitely look into this. One of my thoughts was that eventually the tool that I was building would sync multiple databases across many customers (like a central hub integrating data into data warehouses) many different customer datawarehouses in many locations with an equal number of sources.